# CEF3 single process mode in production

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

Are there any real pitfalls in using single process mode in production? The official statement seems to discourage this, but so far the application has been stable. CEF1 seems to have been abandoned, and if CEF3 single process is used for dev, then the latter should be at the very least be part of the test suite, and therefore stable. Or is that not true?

Also, is CEF3 single process not equivalent to CEF1? The new Battle.net launcher is using CEFl (1453). I wonder if that was for legacy reasons or if that was a conscious decision to avoid using CEF3.

Comment: I am using CEF3 in single process in production without problems, except [this known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=1179) on exit

Comment: Update: We're switching to multi-process mode from single process mode because the latter does not scale well at all in a multi-browser environment

Answer (score 4):

This question is repeated often on [cef's forum](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/). The short answer is "don't take this path".

There are, from time to time, certain bugs that pops up on the single process mode and the official word from cef's maintainer is that this mode is unsupported, period. I think this is worded too lightly on the documentation, though.

People coming from cef1 background tends to keep doing it the old way, so single process mode seems like a good way to go, but the newer (now years old) cef3 highly depends on chromium's internals, and these are solely based on multiple process for production.